# Interactive elements over lock screen on Mobile

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, mobile

Is it possible to insert interactive elements over the lock screen of a mobile phone? More properly, it is an `iframe` to interact with when the screen is locked. The screen lock functions are not altered, so the user should be able to normally lock/unlock the screen.
Then the `iframe` will be shown/hidden with an `animation`.

Are the examples or tutorial online to link? Or do you have an idea or an opinion of how it should be realized? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Y can try view src of  some module from xposed framework, wich contains from modile, that add camera on lock screen  repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer

Comment: Thanks man! But could you post some references or some examples to look at?